# How does correlated relationship implies non zero conditional mean?

Tags: correlation, least-squares, conditional-expectation

i.e. if $cov(X,Y)\neq0$, how do we derive $E(X|Y)\neq0$
it seems that it is quite obvious and usually be taken into granted,
but I just couldn't figure it out in a short time, can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E[X|Y]$ is $0$, by [Law of iterated expectation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_total_expectation), we have $E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]=0$.
Then, for the covariance, we have
$$cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]=E[XY]$$

Again, calculating this expectation using the same law:
$$E[XY]=E[E[XY|Y]]=E[YE[X|Y]]=E[Y.0]=0$$
So, having $E[X|Y]$ is $0$ yields zero-covariance, which means if you have non-zero covariance, conditional expectation cannot be $0$.

Comment: Right, I should have thought of the contrapositive, thanks!